sorting not working when using 'headerComponent' in ag-grid table
i needed to display custom header component for displaying icons and other thing in the colum-header and for that i've used 'headerComponent' in the column definition. But now the issue is that the sorting is not working with 'headerComponent'. Need help
Even sortable: true is not working.
searched a lot about it online and in official docs of ag-grid but, haven't found any resolution.
{
    headerName: 'Content',
    field: 'content_count',
    headerComponent: () => {
        return (
            <AampeTooltip title="The total number of unique sendable message variants attached to this label.">
                <span>Content</span>
            </AampeTooltip>
        );
    },
    sortable: true,
    width: 96,
},


I'm trying to do a similar thing. Sadly, I don't think ag-grid supports this easily.  As far as I can tell you have to either re-implement the functionality of the provided renderer (like sorting) or if your modification is simple enough you can not provide a custom header component but instead just provide a header template. See https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-headers/#provided-component

Did you get any resolution for this?
